# Linking custom made functions php

Tags: php, html

I am a little bit newer to PHP. My question is, my index.php is linked to config.php. But I have a custom function that is linked to common.php.

```
//THIS IS THE INDEX.PHP
<?php

if ( file_exists( 'lib/config.php' ) )
  require_once 'lib/config.php';
else
  echo "Whoops, something went wrong, we're working on a fix.";

html5_page_pre(
  "Yummy Tummy",
  array('style.css')
);

html5_page_post();
?>
```

If I change it to lib/common.php, I get the page to load with errors  due to config.php missing and html5_page_pre is recognized. The function is defined in common.php, how can I leave it has config.php and still have the function linked? As config.php contains the backbone of my database for login, etc.

```
//THIS IS THE CONFIG.PHP
<?php
// database settings
$host = 'localhost'; // database address
$dn = 'test_proj'; // database name
$user = 'test_proj'; // database username
$pass = '******'; // database password
$charset = 'utf8'; // character set

// Root of the website with leading "/"
// e.g: for http://webhost.com/subdomain/my_site, set to "/subdomain/my_site"
$site_root = "/Project/";

// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

/* DO NOT TOUCH BELOW THIS LINE UNLESS YOU ARE A DELEVOPER */
// site's absolute path on the filesystem
$doc_root = $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ];

if ( file_exists( $doc_root . $site_root . 'lib/common.php' ) )
  require_once $doc_root . $site_root . 'lib/common.php';
else
  echo "Whoops, something went wrong, we're working on a fix.";
?>
```

As you can see, I also have common.php linked to config.php at the end. Should it not already load the page without errors? I don't understand why the custom function is not recognized in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want the page to stop processing if those files are missing, you don't need the conditional around the require_once lines. Take the require_once common out of config and have two requires in index.

Answer (score 0):

Move require from config to index.

```
<?php

require_once 'lib/config.php';
require_once 'lib/common.php';

html5_page_pre(
  "Yummy Tummy",
  array('style.css')
);

html5_page_post();
```